# How do I translate the Swedish "lagom" into Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

The expression *lagom* is something that is thought by many Swedish to be unique to the language. It means not too little and not too much: just the right amount. It can be used for anything like the amount of food you eat, how much jewellery you wear, or how much you brag about your kids' school efforts.

Comment: The uniqueness is slightly overstated as Norwegian _passe_ is the same as Swedish _lagom_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word "ĝustamezure" ("just the right amount", "just right") covers it pretty well.

Comment: Depending on the situation, I'd say that "ĝuste" works quite well too.

Comment: Yes, it certainly does.

Answer (score 6):

This situation calls for compounds using *trafa, taŭga, deca, preciza,* etc.

My contribution: *trafkvante*. (I am tempted to write *trafiom* or *taŭgiom*, but that would be awful of me.)

Comment: What do you mean by "This"? Did you forget to add a link?

Comment: A word analogous to _taŭgiom_ would probably be legal in Novial!

Answer (score 2):

Another (unofficial) alternative is the prefix "sil-".  I seem to remember reading a "silisma manifesto" at one point, but the most complete reference I can find now is [this post in soc.culture.esperanto](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/soc.culture.esperanto/JjWQwdFVX5o/4sh8VVe5UtYJ) by Paul Ebermann:

> Krome en la lastaj jaroj ekuzigxis la prefikso "sil-",
>   kiu signifas proksimume
>       "nek ~, nek mal~, sed ie (ne nepre meze) intere".
>
> (Estas junulara inventajxo, same kiel
>    "mojosa" - "modernjunstila" - "cool", ambaux
>    aperis en kunsido de TEJK (TutEuxropa Junulara
>    Konferenco), forumo de kunlaboro inter la euxropaj
>    Esperanto-Junularoj.)

Answer (score 2):

In the [Lernu forum](http://lernu.net/cs/forumo/temo/4647), I found these possible answers, too:
"*laŭmezure*"  "*ĝustamezure*" (Bertilo's answer).

Or *konvena, sufiĉa, trafe*... Or simply "*ne tro*" (which I think covers the Jantelag aspect pretty well.). Which we can adverbize: "netroe".

For the combination "*lagom mängd*" this idea from the forum is pretty good too: "*Ĝusta kvanto*", "*Ĝusta nombro*".

*Nun ni netroe kunumas.* :-D