# Kion mi diru se mi fartas nek bone, nek malbone?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

Se iu demandas al mi: *Kiel vi fartas*? Kion mi respondu kiam mi fartas nek bone, nek malbone. En aliaj lingvoj mi konas *so-und-so* (germana), *comme ci comme ça* (franca) kaj *sådär* (sveda).

Comment: Se mi iel eraris je la aliaj lingvoj, bonvolu koreki min.

Comment: English has _[so-so](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so-so#English)_.

Answer (score 15):

Eblaj respondoj:

Mezbone.

Sufiĉe bone, mi supozas.

Nek bone nek malbone. (Provu: nek nek)

Bonete.

Mi ankoraŭ vivas.

Ne aparte malbone.

Answer (score 8):

Mi diras kutime: *pli malpli ...*

Answer (score 6):

Se vi ne timas neologismojn, vi povus uzi *silbone*, kiu estis [rekomendo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1109/13) en ĝenerala demando pri prefikso por malemfazi iun ajn adjektivon.

Alikaze vi povus diri *mezbone* kiu havas similan signifon kun nur normalaj radikoj.

Answer (score 6):

La respondoj de Tomaso kaj Johannes estas tute bonaj. Mi kutimas uzi *iel tiel*, kio iom pli proksimas al *so-und-so*, *comme ci comme ça*, *așa și așa* kaj similaj nacilingvaĵoj.